# Is there still active research in Euclidean geometry?

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, research

Is there still ongoing and active research in Euclidean geometry? I have heard somewhere that Euclidean geometry is a solved subject with no open problems. But perhaps I heard wrong. Is there still mathematical research literature on Euclidean geometry? If so, can I see some recent or relatively recent research texts on Euclidean geometry? I would be very interested in such references.

Comment: Research for undergraduates or academic research publishable in top research journals? Not the latter, for sure.

Comment: It's certainly not a "solved subject"; people are still finding interesting results. The (retired) online journal [Forum Geometricorum](https://forumgeom.fau.edu/index1.html) had many intriguing articles, and there remain dedicated publications such as the [International Journal of Geometry](https://ijgeometry.com). Members of the [Euclid@Groups.io](http://euclid.groups.io) research mailing list include frequent contributors to the [Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html).

Comment: It depends on what exactly do you mean by Euclidean geometry. Is the existence of an "Einstein tile" a theorem of Euclidean geometry?  And  "I have heard somewhere" is not a good source of information.

Comment: @Blue You should convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of it being *active* in the traditional sense, but it's still valuable and active in different ways.

Despite both being the roots of mathematics, Euclidean geometry is fundamentally different from (Elementary) number theory: While number theory suffers (celebrates?) the Godel's incompleteness theorem, first order Euclidean geometry is [decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms) (though this is a [subtle issue](https://maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Greenberg2011.pdf)). That is, there exists a computer program that can determine any given statement in Euclidean geometry is true or false. This doesn't necessarily kill the field, as Euclidean geometry can be easily shown to be NP-complete, so we would not expect to find an efficient algorithm. And one may still be interested in higher order Euclidean geometry that is not decidable.

Still, Euclidean geometry not only has special places in education (for being practical as well as intellectually challenging) and mathematical competition, but also attracts researchers' attention in developing more efficient algorithms to solve larger class of problems, thus as a test field of computational algebraic geometry ([Grobner's basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) and [Wu's method](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00244942)) and more recently deep learning (or large language models or AI, whatever you want to call it). In particular, [DeepMind's AlphaGeometry](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-023-06747-5) has grabbed a lot of [attention](https://web.archive.org/web/20240128231116/https://www.nytimes.com/2024/01/17/science/ai-computers-mathematics-olympiad.html).